# How to use statistical function (MannWhitneyUTest) from go internal packages

Tags: go, statistics

I am trying to run [Mann-Whiteney-U test](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/perf/internal/stats#MannWhitneyUTest) with following code:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "stats" 
)
func main() {
    e, _ = MannWhitneyUTest([]float64{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
                            []float64{1, 2, 3, 5, 6}, 
                            0) 
    fmt.Println("Mann-WhitneyUTest: ", e)
}
```

However, this gives me this error:

```
$ go run mainstats2.go 
mainstats2.go:5:2: cannot find package "stats" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/stats (from $GOROOT)
        /home/iuser/go/src/stats (from $GOPATH)
```

I have following stats packages installed:

```
$ go list all | grep stats
github.com/montanaflynn/stats
github.com/montanaflynn/stats/examples
golang.org/x/perf/internal/stats
golang.org/x/perf/vendor/github.com/aclements/go-moremath/stats
golang.org/x/perf/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/stats
```

I need stats package golang.org/x/perf/ which I had installed by command: `go get golang.org/x/perf/internal/stats`

I believe this package is already there in go installation and was not needed to be installed separately.

How do I solve this problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: As `go list` reports, there is no package with path "stats".  Perhaps you intended to import "github.com/montanaflynn/stats".

Comment: Oh, you want to import "golang.org/x/perf/internal/stats".  You cannot access this package because it's an internal package.

Comment: Yes, this function is part of "golang.org/x/perf/internal/stats". Why it is not being found? Should I delete `~/go/src/golang.org/x` folder?

Comment: There are two issues.  The first is that the package is an internal package.  See https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Internal_Directories for the rules about importing internal packages. 
 The second issue is that the application does not import "golang.org/x/perf/internal/stats".  The fix is to change the "stats" import to"golang.org/x/perf/internal/stats", but there's no point in doing this given the internal issue.

Comment: "golang.org/x/perf/internal/stats" looks like a really useful package. Why is it restricted to internal use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because your import path is incorrect, it should be:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/perf/internal/stats" 
)
```

But even though import path issue is fixed, you'll get another [error for trying to use internal package](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#internalpackages).

> stats.go:4:5: use of internal package golang.org/x/perf/internal/stats not allowed

I suggest try to find another alternative library.

---

## EDIT #1:

If you insist, there is a workaround. Try to copy the `$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/perf/internal/stats` folder directly into your project, then import it. It worked, please see screenshot below.

[image]

---

## EDIT 2:

> I have copied the folder to ~/go/src/stats. It is still not working. What should I put for import. Currently it is just "stats"

I think you are doing it wrong. First, you need to create what-so-called **project**, it's a folder placed inside `$GOPATH/src`.

For example in image below I created a project called `my-example-app`, placed under `$GOPATH/src`. So the full path of the project will be `$GOPATH/src/my-example-app`.

[image]

Inside my project, I created `main.go` file. This file contains the code (I copied from yours).

Also, I copied the `$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/perf/internal/stats` folder into my project, so the `stats` folder will be on the same level with my `main.go`.

The import of `stats` folder need to be happen relative to the project name, so the correct import path would be:

```golang
import "my-example-app/stats"
```

[image]

Here is content of my `main.go` (copied from yours with some syntax error fix addition).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "my-example-app/stats"
)

func main() {
    e, _ := stats.MannWhitneyUTest([]float64{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        []float64{1, 2, 3, 5, 6},
        0)
    fmt.Println("Mann-WhitneyUTest: ", e)
}
```

Comment: Is there no way possible to use this function: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/perf/internal/stats#MannWhitneyUTest ?

Comment: importing internal packages is not allowed, so there is no other *correct* way. but maybe you can copy the code into your own codebase

Comment: @rnso tested on my local, you can copy the stats folder into your codebase and use it, it's working fine.

Comment: I have copied the folder to `~/go/src/stats`. It is still not working. What should I put for import. Currently it is just "stats"

Comment: @rnso I assume you are new to Go. I suggest to take a look at [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) first. but anyway I'll update the answer shortly

Comment: Thanks for the link. With above changes, `MannWhitneyUTest` is found but`e` is still not found. Error is:  `undefined: e`

Comment: @rnso if you take a look closely in my example, I changed your `e, _ =` code into `e, _ :=`

Comment: Yes, it works now. This is what happens when one tries to change languages. Thanks for your help.